# Codeigniter Controller Execution Time Very Slow

Tags: php, codeigniter, exec

Can anyone helps me with this situation? When I run a Controller/View with a helper method the output time is really slow:

```
BENCHMARKS   
Loading Time: Base Classes      0.0320 
Controller Execution Time ( EquipUser / Detalii )   3.3030 
Total Execution Time    3.3350
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public function detalii($service_tag){
    // 1. Incarcare elementele necesare in pagina
        $this->load->library('javascript');
        $this->load->library('javascript/jquery');
        $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    //2. Definere campuri pentru incarcare in view
        $data['titlu_pagina'] = $service_tag . " "; 
        $data['service_tag'] = $service_tag;
        $data['echipamente'] = $this->Echipament->get_by_service_tag($service_tag);
    //3. Incarcare view principal
        $this->load->view('detalii', $data);
    }
```

The View area:

```
<section id="diverse" class="col-12 col-md-6">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#ping').click(function () {
                var result="<?php echo doPing($echipament->hostname); ?>";
                alert(result);
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
<a class="btn btn-toolbar" id="ping" onclick="ping()">Ping</a>
</section>
```

And helper function:

```
function pingExec_dr($host){
    exec(sprintf('ping -w 1 %s', escapeshellarg($host)), $res, $rval);
    return $rval === 0;
}

function doPing($host){
    $up = pingExec_dr($host);

    if($up){
        $result = "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>";
        $result .= $host . " ONLINE";
        $result .= "</div>";        
    } else {
        $result = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>";
        $result .= $host . " OFFLINE";
        $result .= "</div>";
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I tried also with the PING class from:[GitHub - Ping- geerlingguy][1]
  [1]: https://github.com/geerlingguy/Ping and I have the same timeout, but with the latency of 1ms. 
I have tested the call of method outside jQuery with the same result. 
I have tried the ping methods/class in a different test project (not using CI) and it worked with no delay.

Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Loading Time: Base Classes   0.0410
Controller Execution Time ( EquipUser / Detalii )   3.5224
Total Execution Time   3.5644

Comment: the issue is not with javascript. the issue is with calling the ping/exec function

Comment: When I echo the $latency from the PING class. I get the return immediately and after 3 seconds the page loads with all the data.

Comment: You may try to pinpoint the source of the delay by adding some additional logging or benchmark spots and see what's taking longer than expected. i.e., set a `log_message('debug', 'starting exec);` just before the exec and a `log_message('debug', 'finished exec');` just after the exec and check the timestamps that get logged for both. This may let you see how long that call is taking